# test status is null with custom listener for phpunit

Tags: php, phpunit

I am working on a custom test listener for phpunit and I am unable to get the status of a test after it finishes. When I call getStatus() on the test after it is finished I am getting null instead of the status. I have tried this out on some tests where one passes, one is incomplete and one fails, but getStatus() returns null for all of them.

I am using PHPUnit version 3.7.10

Here is my test listener code:

```
class MyTestListener implements PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener
{
    protected $tests = array();

    public function addError(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, Exception $e, $time) {}
    public function addFailure(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, PHPUnit_Framework_AssertionFailedError $e, $time) {}
    public function addIncompleteTest(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, Exception $e, $time) {}
    public function addSkippedTest(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, Exception $e, $time) {}
    public function startTest(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test) {}
    public function endTest(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, $time) {
        $this->tests[] = array('test'=>$test, 'time'=>$time);
            $status = $test->getStatus();
            //NOTE: $status is null
    }
    public function startTestSuite(PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite $suite) {}
    public function endTestSuite(PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite $suite) {}

    public function __destruct() {
        foreach($this->tests as $d) {
            $test = $d['test'];
            $time = $d['time'];

            $testClass = get_class($test);

            $status = $test->getStatus();
            //NOTE: $status is null here
            if($status == PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner::STATUS_FAILURE) {
                $status = "fail - ";
            } else if($status == PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner::STATUS_SKIPPED) {
                $status = "skip - ";
            } else if($status == PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner::STATUS_INCOMPLETE) {
                $status = "inc  - ";
            } else if($status == PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner::STATUS_ERROR) {
                $status = "err  - ";
            } else {
                $status = $status."ok  - ";
            }

            print $status.$testClass."::".$test->getName()."  ".round($time,1)." seconds\n";

        }
    }
}
```

Anyone have any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interface `PHPUnit_Framework_Test` doesn't even have a `getStatus()` method, so you're likely to run into more problems. Better capture the results in the `add*()` methods.

Have a look at `PHPUnit/TextUI/ResultPrinter.php`, it does it this way.